# internal server error: com.google.gerrit.server.git.UpdateException

Tags: git, gerrit

Just an hour ago it worked fine. Now, when I try to push I met the following error

> ! [remote rejected]       HEAD -> refs/for/master(internal server error: com.google.gerrit.server.git.UpdateException:
> java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is
> closed)

What caused such error?

=======================UPDATE===================

Seems the gerrit server haveing problems? I even cannot clone the project.

> Cloning into 'android'...
> remote: Counting objects: 364705, done
>
> remote: Finding sources: 100% (364705/364705)
>
> Write failed: Connection reset by peer), 111.97 MiB | 11.30 MiB/s
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> fatal: early EOF
>
> fatal: index-pack failed

Comment: I get the same issue now. Any idea the root cause for this issue?

Comment: I suspect it relates to the gerrit server. I didn't change anything. After a while, I succeeded cloning the project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your commit has the same changeId has a commit that has already been merged.

Try to change to another changeId.